# How to extract a database file of my Android Project from Genymotion emulator device in Android Studio 4.2.2 to Local PC for testing purpose?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, pull

I am working on a SQLite application. I am using Genymotion emulator with Android Studio 4.2.2. on OS Ubuntu 20.04

In my Android Studio I need to do

View -> Tool Window -> Device File Explorer

Then under

data -> data -> myprojectfolder -> databases

I can find my database file.

Now I want to pull this file to my Local PC for testing purpose. But I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click over the file in Device File Explorer and choose "Save As" from the context menu:

[image: Device File Explorer context menu]